# Testing react components that have JSS injected styles with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jss

I'm having a react component. Let's say Todo

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import injectSheet from 'react-jss';

class Todo extends Component {

    // methods that incl. state manipulation

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <WhateverElse />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default injectSheet(Todo);
```

I want to test it with enzyme. And there are two problems with it.

**1. Access to the state**
(and other component specific features)

When I `shallow` or `mount` that composer in the suite I can't get access to its state of course because it's not my component anymore but something new around it.

E.g. this code will give me an error:

```js
it('should have state updated on handleAddTodo', () => {
    const todo = shallow(<Todo />);

    const length = todo.state('todos').length;
});
```

It says of course `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` because the state is not what I expect but this: `{ theme: {}, dynamicSheet: undefined }`

This won't also give me access to `props`, `refs` etc.

**2. Problems with theme provider**

To provide some default colouring to the project like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Colors from './whatever/Colors';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={Colors}>
                <WhateverInside />
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

And of course when running tests it gives me an error `[undefined] Please use ThemeProvider to be able to use WithTheme`.

So my question is the following. Is there a way to solve this problem in “one single place”. How can I make enzyme agnostic of what is my component wrapped with?

If not, then how do I solve the problem if passing the ThemeProvider features down to the component that I'm testing?
And how can I access the state, ref, props and other things of the wrapped component?

Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to resolve `Please use ThemeProvider to be able to use WithTheme` in the end? Here's my [attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704909/how-to-traverse-a-shallow-component-nested-in-themeprovider-hoc)

Answer (score 0):

here's what I'd do to test the component,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import injectSheet from 'react-jss';

const styles = {};

class Todo extends Component {

    // methods that incl. state manipulation

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <WhateverElse />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export { styles, Todo as TodoCmp }

export default injectSheet(styles)(Todo);
```

and in the test file, I'd add the following:

```
import { theme } from 'your-theme-source';

const mockReducer = (prev, curr) => Object.assign({}, prev, { [curr]: curr });

const coerceStyles = styles =>
  typeof styles === 'function' ? styles(theme) : styles;

const mockClasses = styles =>
  Object.keys(coerceStyles(styles)).reduce(mockReducer, {});

import {TodoCmp, styles} from 'your-js-file';
// then test as you'd normally.
it('should blah blah', () => {
    const classes = mockClasses(styles);
    const todo = shallow(<Todo classes={classes} />);

    const length = todo.state('todos').length;
})
```

Please read more about it in the [nordnet-ui-kit](https://github.com/nordnet/nordnet-ui-kit) library specifically in the test directory. Here's a quick [example](https://github.com/nordnet/nordnet-ui-kit/blob/master/test/components/button/button.test.js)

Answer (score -2):

1. It is not related to JSS specifically. Any HOC wraps your component. Ideally you don't test any internals of a component directly.

   - Components public api is props, use them to render your component with a specific state and verify the rendered output with shallow renderer.
   - For some edge cases if first and preferred way is impossible, you can access the inner component directly and access whatever you need directly. You will have to mock the props the HOC would pass otherwise for you.

```js
const StyledComponent = injectSheet(styles)(InnerComponent)
console.log(StyledComponent.InnerComponent)
```

2. If your component relies on theming, you have to provide a theme provider, always.